# How can estimate the following integral on $\mathbb S^1$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

For  $d>0$ and $s, t \in \mathbb S^1=\{z\in \mathbb C \mid |z|=1\}$ the unit circle. I need help to give an estimate for the following integral 
$$\int_{\{ s\in \mathbb S^1: \, |s-t|\geq d \}}\frac{ds}{|s-t|}\leq C_d,$$
for all fixed $t  \in \mathbb S^1$, and $C_d$ is a constant depend of  $d>0$.

For $s=e^{i\theta}$ et $r=e^{i\varphi}$, using the following parameterization: $\int_{\mathbb S^1}f(s) \,ds = \int_{\mathbb S^1}f(e^{i\theta}) \,d\theta$ for a function defined on $\mathbb S^1$. Then, we have 
$\begin{align}
\int_{ |s-t|\geq d } \frac{ds}{|s-t|} &=\int_{ |e^{i\theta}-e^{i \varphi}|\geq d } \frac{d\theta}{|e^{i\theta}-e^{i\varphi}|}=\int_{ |1-e^{i(\theta-\varphi)}|\geq d } \frac{d\theta}{|1-e^{i(\theta-\varphi)}|}\\
&=\int_{ \sqrt{2-2\cos(\theta-\varphi)}\geq d } \frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{2-2 \cos(\theta-\varphi)}} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\int_{ 1-\cos(\theta-\varphi)\geq d^2/2 } \frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1-\cos(\theta-\varphi)}} \cdots
\end{align}$

So how to continue if not another track?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Isn't your integral always infinite? Also, your calculations become easier if you use $1-\cos x = 2\sin^2\frac x2$.

Comment: If I'm interpreting it correctly (The integral of the reciprocal of distance to a chosen point on $S_1$ over a region of $S_1$ not too far away from that point), then it would indeed diverge.

Comment: The domain of integration is $\{ s\in \mathbb S^1: \, |s-t|\geq d \}$, I'm sorry!!!

Comment: How good must be the estimate? An utterly trivial bound is $2\pi/d$.

Comment: And you can suppose wlog that $t = 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a figure! Then you'll see that your integral is
$$J(d)=2\int_\alpha^\pi {1\over 2\sin{\phi\over2}}\>d\phi$$
whereby $\alpha$ is defined by $\>2\sin{\alpha\over2}=d$. Replace this by
$$J(d)=2\int_\beta^{\pi/2}{1\over\sin\psi}\>d\psi,\qquad 2\sin\beta=d\ .$$
This amounts to
$$J(d)=-2\log\left(\tan{\beta\over2}\right),\qquad 2\sin\beta=d\ .$$
Letting $\tan{\beta\over2}=:\tau$ we have $$d=2\sin\beta={4\tau\over 1+\tau^2}\ ,$$ 
and therefore
$$\tau={d\over2+\sqrt{4-d^2}}\ .$$
It follows that
$$J(d)=\log{1\over\tau^2}=\log{8-d^2+4\sqrt{4-d^2}\over d^2}\leq{3\over d}\qquad(0<d\leq2)\ .$$
The last estimate comes from inspecting a plot. Note that  for any $\alpha>0$ one has $\log t\leq t^\alpha$ for large $t>0$.

Comment: @ Christian Blatter, with this estimate $J(d)\leq \log(\frac{16}{d^2})$, is what has the following estimate $J(d)\leq C d^{-1}$, where $C$ is a constant $C>0$?

Answer (score 1):

WLOG you can suppose  $t = 1$ ($\varphi = 0$). And your integral has elementary primitive:
$$
\int\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1-\cos(\theta)}} =
\frac{2\sin(\theta/2)\log\tan(\theta/4)}{\sqrt{1 - \cos\theta}} + C
$$
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int(1%2Fsqrt(1+-+cos+t),t)